# Virtualbox Windows XP VM not getting assigned IP, but getting host IP instead

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ip, virtualbox, gateway

I have a Server 2008 R2 as host OS, and XP SP3 as guest OS. (Using VBOX and NAT connection)
The host ip is xxx.xxx.xx.47 and the guest ip is xxx.xxx.xx.91.
I assigned xxx.xxx.xx.91 to the VM but when I go check on SHOWIP sites, I'm still getting the host IP. (xxx.xxx.xx.47)

Here's what my Internet Protocol Properties on the VM looks like :

(To fill these I typed ipconfig , copied and pasted them, changing only the IP address)
Use the following IP address :
IP address : xxx.xxx.xxx.91
Subnet mask : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway : 10.0.2.2 (I've been told the default gateway is xxx.xxx.xxx.1 , but this way I cannot connect to internet at all)

Use the following DNS server addresses :
Preferred DNS server : xx.xxx.xxx.2
Alternate DNS server : xx.xxx.xxx.3

What's going on ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using NAT, you need to use a bridged adapter in virtual box, and it will be as if it is another machine on the network.